# Trouble understanding instructions to install gremlim plugin on neo4j

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, gremlin

I am trying to install the [gremlin plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin) for neo4j 2.1.4 on OS X 1.9.4

The instructions say to run these commands

```
mvn clean package
unzip target/neo4j-gremlin-plugin-2.1-SNAPSHOT-server-plugin.zip -d $NEO4J_HOME/plugins/gremlin-plugin
cd $NEO4J_HOME
bin/neo4j restart
```

I am confused by two things.

1) when I run `maven clean package` I get this error.  I would think you would run maven to build a project -- but it seems like the gremlin plugin instructions say to run it before downloading the source.

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2) What is the meaning of target in this line of code? I would think that you are unzipping code that you have downloaded into the plugins directory of neo4j. But why does that line come after the mvn line? Wouldn't you unzip, cd to /gremlin-plugin and then run `maven clean package`?

```
unzip target/neo4j-gremlin-plugin-2.1-SNAPSHOT-server-plugin.zip -d $NEO4J_HOME/plugins/gremlin-plugin
```

I am doing the following:

1. download zip file from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin
2. unzip to $NEO4J_HOME/plugins/gremlin-plugin
3. reboot neo4j

I get:

```
LookupError: ({'status': '404', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '752', 'server': 'Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)'}, '{\n  "message" : "No such ServerPlugin: \\"GremlinPlugin\\"",\n  "exception" : "PluginLookupException",\n  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLookupException",\n  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.extension(PluginManager.java:115)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:156)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)" ]\n}')
```

How can I follow the gremlin plugin instructions?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to build the plugin from source, then do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/thinkaurelius/neo4j-gremlin-plugin.git
cd neo4j-gremlin-plugin
# now follow the instructions (build, unzip, restart Neo4j server)
```

Your steps to install the prebuilt plugin look good to me. When do you get the LookupError?  When you restart Neo4j or when you try to use the plugin via curl or whatever? Did you add the plugin in `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j-server.properties`?

I also created a video that should answer all remaining questions:

[Install and use Neo4j Gremlin plugin](http://youtu.be/dbBtCIxZ9Ig)